# In Requirejs, can I register the same path by different names?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, modularity

I'm using RequireJS to manage an app that is implemented as an undetermined number of classes split across files.

The app has some some utility classes, and then some consumer classes which use the utility classes. Each consumer class uses RequireJS to load only the utility classes it needs, and is responsible for its own Require config.

Consumer classes aren't aware of each other, and the app as a whole doesn't know the needs of each consume class. It merely knows the consumer class exists, and loads it. The problem is, if two different consumer classes define the same path but with different names, the first one wins, and subsequent one times out.

For example, this is some utility.js

```
define( function(){
    return function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    };  
});
```

This is consumer1.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        ut1: '/utility'
    }
});
require(['ut1'], function(utility){
    utility('hello from client1');
})
```

And this is consumer2.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        ut2: '/utility'
    }
});
require(['ut2'], function(utility){
    utility('hello from client2');
})
```

If used independently each consumer class works, but when called together, the second one returns an error "Load timeout for modules: ut2".

As part of the modular nature of the app design, consumer classes cannot know each other's content, so I cannot enforce naming rules, nor can I have a central app-level require.config. How can I stop one consumer from breaking another's require config?

I supposed I could write a global helper that managed names and paths, grouping common paths and returning the first path name only, but I'd prefer a simpler solution within Require itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`map` option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map):

```
map: {
    consumer1: {
        ut1: '/utility'
    },
    consumer2: {
        ut2: '/utility'
    }
}
```

And then you don't need a `paths` configuration for `/utility`. What this does is tell RequireJS that when `consumer1` requires `ut1`, it should load the `/utility` module instead. When `consumer2` requires `ut2`, RequireJS should load the `/utility` module instead.

Comment: Not sure how that helps. I still end up with having to group all my maps in one place, which breaks the modular design I want. I'll edit my question to make that part clearer.

Comment: You should be able to split `map` just like you split `paths`.

Comment: Ah, got it to work, thanks (Requirejs's documentation can be a bit terse). It imposes the additional restriction that each consumer class must be wrapped in define(), so it would look like

define('consumer1', ['ut1'], function(utility){
    utility('hello from client1');
});

I can live with that.

Comment: Yeah, generally you want your modules to be in a `define` call. I did not notice you did not use `define` when I read your question.